# Global Header Staging in Bazel

Tags: bazel

Our current project structure is as follows:

```
    thirdparty(ws_root)
    |_WORKSPACE
    |_comp1
    |    |_BUILD
    |    |_src
    |        |_ a.c
    |    |_include
    |        |_ a.h
    |_comp2
    |    |_BUILD
    |    |_src
    |        |_ b.c
    |    |_include
    |        |_ b.h
    |_inc
    |   |_comp1
    |          |_a.h
    |   |_comp2
    |          |_b.h
```

Contents of a.c :

```
#include <comp1/a.h>
```

With our current build system the header file under **thirdparty/comp1/include/a.h** is staged with the following path:

```
thirdparty/inc/comp1/a.h
```

Here the **thirdparty/inc** folder is a global location where all header files in the workspace are staged under the respective components.

I would like to know if Bazel provides a mechanism by which we can stage the header files in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, by "global location" you mean a folder in each library (library in the Bazel sense, you might call it component or package)? That's what I understood from the example. If that is the case, and each library just provides a `-isystem` include to all its dependents, that is possible in bazel, look for [includes attribute](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.includes).

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I meant by global location is that, with the above example, we create directory with following path  
   thirdparty/inc/comp1 and place a.h under that

Comment: That's not what I see in the example. There I see thirdparty/comp1/(src|include), possibly thirdparty/comp2/(src|include) etc. For this case my answer is valid.

It is not valid for thirdparty/(src|include)/comp1 and thirdparty/(src|include)/comp2. That would only work if entire thirdparty was a single cc_library. Feel free to edit the question to have a nice formatting, it's harder to explaing this in comment.

Comment: Made the necessary changes to the question. Hope it helps.

Comment: I see now. Thank you. So bazel doesn't need the headers to be in the thirdparty/inc for itself. If you need them there for other rules, you can solve it in bazel using build/skylark macro that will create a cc_library and also a genrule that will copy the headers over.